# How do to install pyreadstat using anaconda?

Tags: python, package, conda, spss

I tried installing pyreadstat because i want to use it to transform .sav file to excel or csv by typing the commands:

```
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" pyreadstat
conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat
```

However, I got "package not found" error.

Comment: It is working correctly for me on Python 3.10. What version of Python are you running? Worst case you could use pip, but only as a last resort.

Comment: python 3.8. Also, I've tried to download it pip  however I received an error :
Failed Building wheel for pyreadstat

Comment: What platform? e.g., **win-64**, **osx-arm64**, etc. Also, don't use labels - I know Anaconda Cloud lists them by default, which makes them seem like something recommended, but they only have advanced use cases.

Comment: Which version of pip were you running? If pip is trying to build from source instead of picking up the wheel, upgrade pip first.

Answer (score 1):

You can always install it using pipy, inside an anaconda environment. Just make sure you have pip installed on your env.

So, from a new environment would be something like this

```
conda activate your_env
conda install pip
pip install pyreadstat
```

Also, have you tried with conda forge?

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat
```

Comment: both of them didn't work, unfortunately.  The first one generated an error "Failed building wheel for pyreadstat" and the second also didn't work generating a Package not found error

Comment: `pip install git+https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat.git` this one maybe?